# How to color a region of an image in C++?

Tags: c++, opencv

I would like to set all the pixels in a region of an image to the same color. I couldn't find how to do that in C++ using Opencv, if anyone can please help. I found this code in Python but it doesn't work for C++:
It starts from the x,y coords of the region(bottom right of the image segment) up until the given x+width and y+height.

```
 img[child.getX():child.getX()+child.getW(), child.getY():child.getY()+child.getH(),0]=val.B; 
 img[child.getX():child.getX()+child.getW(), child.getY():child.getY()+child.getH(),1]=val.G; 
 img[child.getX():child.getX()+child.getW(), child.getY():child.getY()+child.getH(),2]=val.R
```

;

Comment: There are no list slicing and multiindexing in C++. You need loops.

Comment: no you don't need loops

Comment: You posted a Python code and ask for a C++ translation. I'm not rude. I'm just telling you the rules: _"Don't ask about...

Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"_ [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the rectangle. OpenCV calls it a "region of interest" (ROI).

Then call the Mat instance with that rectangle... sounds strange but bear with me.

Now you have a view into the original Mat. Any changes happen to the same memory, and you see the changes in either object.

Now you can use the `setTo` method to fill the ROI with your color.

```c++
#include <string>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

int main()
{
    // load a picture
    std::string image_path { cv::samples::findFile("lena.jpg") };
    cv::Mat img { cv::imread(image_path) };

    // define the region
    cv::Rect rect { 100, 50, 200, 100 };

    // here the img object is called with the rectangle
    cv::Mat roi { img(rect) };

    // show both Mat instances
    cv::imshow("img", img);
    cv::imshow("roi", roi);
    cv::waitKey(-1); // waits forever. press a key?

    // fill with one color
    roi.setTo(cv::Scalar(255, 0, 255));

    cv::imshow("img", img);
    cv::imshow("roi", roi);
    cv::waitKey(-1);

    // all in one expression
    img(cv::Rect(150, 100, 100, 100)).setTo(cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0));
    
    cv::imshow("img", img);
    cv::imshow("roi", roi);
    cv::waitKey(-1);

    return 0;
}
```